# agm-marker change iconUrl on mouseover

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and Angular Maps and have only had limited experience using Google Maps Api so I apologize if I'm missing something obvious here.

I am trying to change the the iconUrl of my agm-marker on mouseOver so that my Blue icon switches to a Green one. I am having no luck and the furthest I have gotten is changing all of the icons to Green on mouseOver.

Here is my current map.component.html

```
<agm-marker *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [latitude]="item.lat"
 [longitude]="item.lng"
 [iconUrl]="{url: icon, origin: {x:0, y:-3}}"
 [label]="{text: item.amount | shorthandThousand: 1, color: '#FFFFFF', fontSize: '12px'}"
 (mouseOver)="mouseOver(item, i)"></agm-marker>
```

I have tried a slew of different options to get this working in my component.ts, I know I need to use the index, but can't figure out how.

Here is my map.component.ts

```
import { Listing } from'../../listing';
import { ListingService } from '../../listing.service';
@Component({selector: 'app-map',templateUrl: './map.component.html',styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']})
export class MapViewComponent implements OnInit {
listings: Listing[];
constructor(private listingService: ListingService) { }
// google maps zoom level
zoom: number = 14;
// Center Lat Lng
centerLat: number = 40.500598;
centerLng: number = -74.447142;
//Marker specific
zindex: number = 1;
iconBlue: string = '/img/map-icon-blue.svg';
iconGreen: string = '/img/map-icon-green.svg';
icon = this.iconBlue;
mouseOver(listing, i){
this.icon = this.iconGreen;
}
ngOnInit() {this.getListings();}
getListings(): void {
this.listingService.getListings()
.subscribe(listings => this.listings = listings);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set marker icon you could use [`AgmMarker.iconUrl` property](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/AgmMarker.html#iconUrl), for example:

```
<agm-marker 
    *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
    [latitude]="m.lat"
    [longitude]="m.lng"
    [label]="m.label"
    [iconUrl]="m.icon"
    (mouseOver)="mouseOver(m, i)">  
</agm-marker>


mouseOver(m: marker, i:number){
    m.icon = "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png";
}
```

Here is [the demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo-ag6iem) for your reference

Comment: is there a way to do this where I have two images, blue and green. I have it working by having the first icon, blue image, declared as 'icon: /img/blue.svg' in my database for every single marker. Then in the <agm-marker> referencing m.icon. And in the component i have your above code to toggle it to /img/green.svg on mouseOver. I'd like to have it where I do not need to have the icon image path stored in my db to start, but rather have it stored in my component I tried icon = '/img/blue.svg' in my component then toggling with icon not m.icon but it changs all the icons when i do